# Darken and Lighten colors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need return Color tones for a specific color for example I have `#4a4a4a` can return `#494949, #666464` using JS. If any package do it please suggest me.

[image: color]

***example using above picture***

if there way if have any color in picture return another .  if have `#E3F2FD` return #BBDFFB, #90CAF9, etx

Comment: There's no such thing as similar color. Do you intend to compute a shade of an existing color? Please phrase some kind of deterministic formula to compute your target color.

Comment: i mean degree for color @MoritzRoessler

Comment: You need to be more specific. By what logic should #4a4a4a return #494949 and/or #666464?

Comment: please check @GuyIncognito

Comment: Again, you need to be more specific. Are those values from some existing color theory model, or did you pick them yourself? If you just want a value from an existing list of colors that's pretty trivial to do.

Comment: Those are material ui colors, right? They have a method to compute shades iirc.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler yes i need how do it ,  i check anwsers

Comment: Take a look at my answer simply darken lighten by -4(for darken 4 steps) or 10(for lighten 10 steps)

Comment: @Hexception i check it now i think very simple

Comment: I have spot a little bug if it 0 wait 1 moment

Comment: So now it becomes solid for production

Comment: I updated my answer, it uses a lookup map to compute the next/previous value from the material ui color palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and working JS:

```js
function changeColor(color, amount) { // #FFF not supportet rather use #FFFFFF
    const clamp = (val) => Math.min(Math.max(val, 0), 0xFF)
    const fill = (str) => ('00' + str).slice(-2)

    const num = parseInt(color.substr(1), 16)
    const red = clamp((num >> 16) + amount)
    const green = clamp(((num >> 8) & 0x00FF) + amount)
    const blue = clamp((num & 0x0000FF) + amount)
    return '#' + fill(red.toString(16)) + fill(green.toString(16)) + fill(blue.toString(16))
}

console.log(changeColor('#EEEEEE', -1110000)) // darken -1110000 will cap at #000000
console.log(changeColor('#EEEEEE', 2)) // lighten 2 steps
console.log(changeColor('#BBAC78', -4)) // darken 4 steps
```

Comment: I love your function Thanks @Hexception

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to get the next shade from the set of material ui values, you can use the following [JSON File](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kawanet/a880c83f06d6baf742e45ac9ac52af96/raw/b4fbc9a730394eb977277e73cc37b60955463f21/material-colors.json) to lookup the next/previous value.

```js
const grouped = Object.values(materialColors).map(o => Object.values(o));

function wrapIndex(i, i_max) {
   return ((i % i_max) + i_max) % i_max;
}

function getShade (hex, step) {
  hex = hex.toLowerCase();
  for (var group of grouped) {
    var ind = group.indexOf(hex);
    if (!!~ind) break;
  }

  return group[wrapIndex(ind + step, group.length)]
}

console.log (getShade('#E3F2FD', -1)) //#2962ff (the a700 shade of  blue)
console.log (getShade('#e3f2fd', 1)) //#bbdefb
console.log (getShade('#bbdefb', 1)) //#90caf9
console.log (getShade('#90caf9', 1)) //#64b5f6
```

```html
<script>
var materialColors = {
  "red": {
    "50": "#ffebee",
    "100": "#ffcdd2",
    "200": "#ef9a9a",
    "300": "#e57373",
    "400": "#ef5350",
    "500": "#f44336",
    "600": "#e53935",
    "700": "#d32f2f",
    "800": "#c62828",
    "900": "#b71c1c",
    "a100": "#ff8a80",
    "a200": "#ff5252",
    "a400": "#ff1744",
    "a700": "#d50000"
  },
  "pink": {
    "50": "#fce4ec",
    "100": "#f8bbd0",
    "200": "#f48fb1",
    "300": "#f06292",
    "400": "#ec407a",
    "500": "#e91e63",
    "600": "#d81b60",
    "700": "#c2185b",
    "800": "#ad1457",
    "900": "#880e4f",
    "a100": "#ff80ab",
    "a200": "#ff4081",
    "a400": "#f50057",
    "a700": "#c51162"
  },
  "purple": {
    "50": "#f3e5f5",
    "100": "#e1bee7",
    "200": "#ce93d8",
    "300": "#ba68c8",
    "400": "#ab47bc",
    "500": "#9c27b0",
    "600": "#8e24aa",
    "700": "#7b1fa2",
    "800": "#6a1b9a",
    "900": "#4a148c",
    "a100": "#ea80fc",
    "a200": "#e040fb",
    "a400": "#d500f9",
    "a700": "#aa00ff"
  },
  "deeppurple": {
    "50": "#ede7f6",
    "100": "#d1c4e9",
    "200": "#b39ddb",
    "300": "#9575cd",
    "400": "#7e57c2",
    "500": "#673ab7",
    "600": "#5e35b1",
    "700": "#512da8",
    "800": "#4527a0",
    "900": "#311b92",
    "a100": "#b388ff",
    "a200": "#7c4dff",
    "a400": "#651fff",
    "a700": "#6200ea"
  },
  "indigo": {
    "50": "#e8eaf6",
    "100": "#c5cae9",
    "200": "#9fa8da",
    "300": "#7986cb",
    "400": "#5c6bc0",
    "500": "#3f51b5",
    "600": "#3949ab",
    "700": "#303f9f",
    "800": "#283593",
    "900": "#1a237e",
    "a100": "#8c9eff",
    "a200": "#536dfe",
    "a400": "#3d5afe",
    "a700": "#304ffe"
  },
  "blue": {
    "50": "#e3f2fd",
    "100": "#bbdefb",
    "200": "#90caf9",
    "300": "#64b5f6",
    "400": "#42a5f5",
    "500": "#2196f3",
    "600": "#1e88e5",
    "700": "#1976d2",
    "800": "#1565c0",
    "900": "#0d47a1",
    "a100": "#82b1ff",
    "a200": "#448aff",
    "a400": "#2979ff",
    "a700": "#2962ff"
  },
  "lightblue": {
    "50": "#e1f5fe",
    "100": "#b3e5fc",
    "200": "#81d4fa",
    "300": "#4fc3f7",
    "400": "#29b6f6",
    "500": "#03a9f4",
    "600": "#039be5",
    "700": "#0288d1",
    "800": "#0277bd",
    "900": "#01579b",
    "a100": "#80d8ff",
    "a200": "#40c4ff",
    "a400": "#00b0ff",
    "a700": "#0091ea"
  },
  "cyan": {
    "50": "#e0f7fa",
    "100": "#b2ebf2",
    "200": "#80deea",
    "300": "#4dd0e1",
    "400": "#26c6da",
    "500": "#00bcd4",
    "600": "#00acc1",
    "700": "#0097a7",
    "800": "#00838f",
    "900": "#006064",
    "a100": "#84ffff",
    "a200": "#18ffff",
    "a400": "#00e5ff",
    "a700": "#00b8d4"
  },
  "teal": {
    "50": "#e0f2f1",
    "100": "#b2dfdb",
    "200": "#80cbc4",
    "300": "#4db6ac",
    "400": "#26a69a",
    "500": "#009688",
    "600": "#00897b",
    "700": "#00796b",
    "800": "#00695c",
    "900": "#004d40",
    "a100": "#a7ffeb",
    "a200": "#64ffda",
    "a400": "#1de9b6",
    "a700": "#00bfa5"
  },
  "green": {
    "50": "#e8f5e9",
    "100": "#c8e6c9",
    "200": "#a5d6a7",
    "300": "#81c784",
    "400": "#66bb6a",
    "500": "#4caf50",
    "600": "#43a047",
    "700": "#388e3c",
    "800": "#2e7d32",
    "900": "#1b5e20",
    "a100": "#b9f6ca",
    "a200": "#69f0ae",
    "a400": "#00e676",
    "a700": "#00c853"
  },
  "lightgreen": {
    "50": "#f1f8e9",
    "100": "#dcedc8",
    "200": "#c5e1a5",
    "300": "#aed581",
    "400": "#9ccc65",
    "500": "#8bc34a",
    "600": "#7cb342",
    "700": "#689f38",
    "800": "#558b2f",
    "900": "#33691e",
    "a100": "#ccff90",
    "a200": "#b2ff59",
    "a400": "#76ff03",
    "a700": "#64dd17"
  },
  "lime": {
    "50": "#f9fbe7",
    "100": "#f0f4c3",
    "200": "#e6ee9c",
    "300": "#dce775",
    "400": "#d4e157",
    "500": "#cddc39",
    "600": "#c0ca33",
    "700": "#afb42b",
    "800": "#9e9d24",
    "900": "#827717",
    "a100": "#f4ff81",
    "a200": "#eeff41",
    "a400": "#c6ff00",
    "a700": "#aeea00"
  },
  "yellow": {
    "50": "#fffde7",
    "100": "#fff9c4",
    "200": "#fff59d",
    "300": "#fff176",
    "400": "#ffee58",
    "500": "#ffeb3b",
    "600": "#fdd835",
    "700": "#fbc02d",
    "800": "#f9a825",
    "900": "#f57f17",
    "a100": "#ffff8d",
    "a200": "#ffff00",
    "a400": "#ffea00",
    "a700": "#ffd600"
  },
  "amber": {
    "50": "#fff8e1",
    "100": "#ffecb3",
    "200": "#ffe082",
    "300": "#ffd54f",
    "400": "#ffca28",
    "500": "#ffc107",
    "600": "#ffb300",
    "700": "#ffa000",
    "800": "#ff8f00",
    "900": "#ff6f00",
    "a100": "#ffe57f",
    "a200": "#ffd740",
    "a400": "#ffc400",
    "a700": "#ffab00"
  },
  "orange": {
    "50": "#fff3e0",
    "100": "#ffe0b2",
    "200": "#ffcc80",
    "300": "#ffb74d",
    "400": "#ffa726",
    "500": "#ff9800",
    "600": "#fb8c00",
    "700": "#f57c00",
    "800": "#ef6c00",
    "900": "#e65100",
    "a100": "#ffd180",
    "a200": "#ffab40",
    "a400": "#ff9100",
    "a700": "#ff6d00"
  },
  "deeporange": {
    "50": "#fbe9e7",
    "100": "#ffccbc",
    "200": "#ffab91",
    "300": "#ff8a65",
    "400": "#ff7043",
    "500": "#ff5722",
    "600": "#f4511e",
    "700": "#e64a19",
    "800": "#d84315",
    "900": "#bf360c",
    "a100": "#ff9e80",
    "a200": "#ff6e40",
    "a400": "#ff3d00",
    "a700": "#dd2c00"
  },
  "brown": {
    "50": "#efebe9",
    "100": "#d7ccc8",
    "200": "#bcaaa4",
    "300": "#a1887f",
    "400": "#8d6e63",
    "500": "#795548",
    "600": "#6d4c41",
    "700": "#5d4037",
    "800": "#4e342e",
    "900": "#3e2723"
  },
  "grey": {
    "50": "#fafafa",
    "100": "#f5f5f5",
    "200": "#eeeeee",
    "300": "#e0e0e0",
    "400": "#bdbdbd",
    "500": "#9e9e9e",
    "600": "#757575",
    "700": "#616161",
    "800": "#424242",
    "900": "#212121"
  },
  "bluegrey": {
    "50": "#eceff1",
    "100": "#cfd8dc",
    "200": "#b0bec5",
    "300": "#90a4ae",
    "400": "#78909c",
    "500": "#607d8b",
    "600": "#546e7a",
    "700": "#455a64",
    "800": "#37474f",
    "900": "#263238"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is using transparency which isn't used for darken lighten. You code works with percentages with is very bad since 0.5 and 1.5 are completely different things. And if you want to darken by the same range as lighten you can't simply type -2 you have to calculate the percentages.

Comment: @Hexception Thanks for pointing that out. What would be the right way to do that? Convert to HSV, increase/decrease **value** and convert back to rgb again?

Comment: Look at my answer. May you also have some critic on that solution.